# OpenAI API: How do I print all available OpenAI models in Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, model, google-colaboratory, openai-api

I want to print the available OpenAI models in Google Colab.

I installed and imported the OpenAI Python SDK, provided the API key, and called the list function, but I'm getting the following error:

> You tried to access openai.Model, but this is no longer supported in
> openai>=1.0.0

This is my code:

```
!pip install openai
import openai
openai.api_key = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
openai.Model.list()
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The SDK has changed significantly and the error message gives guidance. Follow the links to work out what to do. https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

Answer (score 0):

**You're trying to list models using the wrong method name (i.e., `openai.Model.list()`).**

What you're trying to use worked with the OpenAI Python SDK <`v1`, but you have >=`v1`.

The following is the correct model listing method name if you're using >=`v1`:

```
client.models.list()
```

See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list).